# Setting 'upstream' settings for git on my machine (using command line)?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am having a bit of a struggle setting the upstream settings (and origin) for git using remotes and w/o using the gui (trying to break free here). My professor said it was weird that git didn't do it correctly for me...and has even suspected that the [gitHub for Windows GUI clinet](https://help.github.com/articles/do-i-need-ssh-keys-to-use-github-for-windows/) may have set up SSH for me -- but now the command line client doesn't "get it".

Does anyone know a way out of this mess?

Currently, here is what I am getting:

```
P$ C:\Users\SomeFolder\MyName> git remote -v 
MyName https://github.com/MyName/ClassFolder/tree/master/students (fetch)
MyName https://github.com/MyName/ClassFolder/tree/master/students (push)
upstream https://github.com/MyName/ClassFolder (fetch)
upstream https://github.com/MyName/ClassFolder (push)

P$ C:\Users\SomeFolder\MyName> git push MyName
warning: push function is unset; its implicit value is changing in Git 2.0 from matching to simple....
```

WHAT I need though is for it to look like this:

```
$ git remote -v

origin  https://github.com/MyName/IntroToPython.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/MyName/IntroToPython.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/ClassFolder/IntroToPython.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/ClassFolder/IntroToPython.git (push)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Add origin remote since it doesn't exist

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/MyName/IntroToPython.git
```

#### Set url of existing remote

```
git remote set-url upstream https://github.com/ClassFolder/IntroToPython.git
```

#### Delete unused remote

```
git remote -d MyName
```

See [git-remote](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

#### NOTE

The URL you intend to set for your remote:

```
https://github.com/MyName/IntroToPython.git
```

It's in the format for cloning.  You can pull, but not to push to it.  To push it should be

```
git@github.com:MyName/IntroToPython.git
```